# DataBinding V2 Crashes in multi module android Projects

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, androidx

I have enabled data binding in all the android modules, I'm having `Jetifier,AndroidX, and databinding v2 enabled` I have no compile-time issues, But when I run the app it crashes because `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)` returns null.
I'm seeing is the following code in app module

```
public class DataBinderMapperImpl extends MergedDataBinderMapper {
DataBinderMapperImpl() {
  addMapper(new com.mobile.test.DataBinderMapperImpl());
 }
}
```

It's clear that it doesn't inclued DataBindingMapper from UI module, which includes the layout that I'm trying to inflate. Could someone help me regarding how to fix this issue?